# how do I make my essay impactful?

Tags: writing-advice

I have the ideas but I cant pen them down.I get the following problems while writing an essay:
1. I dont know where to start or end.
2. I cant maintain continuity in my essay.
3. my language skills arent impactful at all.
I know the solution lies in practising writing . but maybe it will be easier if I can get some tips.
thank you in advance :)

Comment: Write stuff the reader will want to read, even if it isn't perfectly written.

Comment: I would suggest that you ask your question on [**Writing.SE**](https://writing.stackexchange.com/), maybe show the first two sentences from an introductory  paragraph and ask how they might be improved.

Comment: Don't forget apostrophes when you write contracted words and proper punctuation, you want to make a positive impression.

Comment: This site isn't for writing advice, but before this is closed I suggest you avoid words like impactful and try to write plain straightforward English like "have impact". This has more impact.

Answer (score 1):

If you have thoughts it should not be difficult.
1. Write down your thoughts as they are (brainstorming)
2. Create a simple outline (intro, body, conclusion).
3. Organize your writing according to your outline.
4. Read your essay to see if it makes sense.

Comment: This particular question will be closed down soon on a technicality. This will lose you some points. Don't take umbrage; contribute to the site again soon.

Answer (score 1):

My brother, who takes lots of courses (in travel writing, modern literature, journalism) always picks my writing to bits. He says that what I ought to do is write a first paragraph which includes all those ideas (the ones you jotted down before you started). What you're saying is : listen up this is what I have to say.

Then you write a paragraph for each of these ideas. Ideally finish each paragraph with a link.  That's dealt with. Now, for the next.

Your first paragraph probably helped you see the order and sequence of ideas.

When you have mastered this master plan, then push the boundaries. That's the only bit I'm good at.

Then, my brother says, you write a final paragraph which mentions all your ideas and says 'That 's what I have to say.'